# Run function is not running in time

Tags: angularjs

All I'm attempting to do is acquire a json array via ajax using angular.js

```
var model = { user: 'Jimmy', items:[]}
var ToDoApp = angular.module('ToDoApp', []);

ToDoApp.run(function($http){
    $http.get('api/todo.json').success(function(data){
        model.items = data; // would have thought this line would do the trick
        console.log( model['items'] ); //-> returns data from my .json file
    });
});

ToDoApp.controller('TasksController', function($scope){
    console.log( model['items'] ); //-> returns '[]', expected data from my .json file
});
```

The ajax is completely sound, as evidenced by my first `console.log( model['items'] );` which returns data from my .json file. However, in my controller, `console.log( model['items'] );` returns an empty array, which was defined in my model variable.

So my run function is being run too late (I think). How should I retrieve data from a json file?

Comment: Why don't you put the ajax function inside the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Because your model is injected earlier then request resolved. Better to resolve you model data from router. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) you can find more about resolving from router